# How do i convert python project into exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

```
I have the following folders in my project
1. fire.py
2.main.py
3.traffic.avi   #video file
4. vechile.py
```

- My program main.py imports fire.py and vechile.py and the main program requires this video 
  traffic.avi .
  Now how do I convert this entire thing into one executable file.
  I want the entire project to run when the .exe is created.
  Single file can be converted into exe file using pyinstaller but how do i convert this type of 
  project containing video file and the main.py importing two python files fire.py and vechile.py and

taking input video traffic.avi for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `py2exe`
There is also GUI available for `py2exe`.
Download Link https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe

`py2exe` is a distutils extension which allows to build standalone Windows executable programs (32-bit and 64-bit) from Python scripts; Python 3.3 and later are supported. It can build console executables, windows (GUI) executables, windows services, and DLL/EXE COM servers.

Comment: I have used this application but how do you put a video file and other python file into the executable file.

Comment: you can directly copy and paste non programming files where the exe is generated

Comment: That is not working ....suggest a method to include all of them in single .exe file

Comment: I was tried that also some time back, What my experience is if you create a single .exe file it will not work dont know why but i could not do that however i was able to create exe with lot of extra stuff added by auto_py_to_exe automatically, (I left single file checkbox unchecked)

Comment: what is auto_py and how do you do it ..could you add the method how to do it?

Comment: its a GUI program for py2exe, just download it and run, you will see many options there, select a .py file and make the exe